# Adding column conditioning on the other columns

Tags: r

I want to create a new column `z` based on the values of `x` and `y`.  If `x>y`, `z=y` otherwise `z=x`.

```
x  y  
3  4 
5  2
6  6
1  7
9  4
```

Output required:

```
x  y  z
3  4  3
5  2  2
6  6  6
1  7  1
9  4  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` :

```
df$z <- with(df, ifelse(x > y, y, x))
#Or without with
#df$z <- ifelse(df$x > df$y, df$y, df$x)
df

#  x y z
#1 3 4 3
#2 5 2 2
#3 6 6 6
#4 1 7 1
#5 9 4 4
```

---

In `dplyr`, you can use `if_else` which is same as above or `case_when` which is helpful when you have to list down multiple conditions.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(z = case_when(x > y ~ y,
                      TRUE ~x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you are looking for minimum value out of several columns. You can use **pmin** function:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(3,5,6,1,9), 
                 y = c(4,2,6,7,4))

df <- df %>% mutate(z = pmin(x, y))
```

result:

```
> df
  x y z
1 3 4 3
2 5 2 2
3 6 6 6
4 1 7 1
5 9 4 4
```

It will count minimum value in a data frame row wise and will simplify syntax if you would like to include more than 2 columns:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(3, 5, 6, 1, 9), 
                 y = c(4, 2, 6, 7, 4),
                 a = c(2, 5, 7, 3, 3))

df <- df %>% mutate(z = pmin(x, y, a))
```

result:

```
> df
  x y a z
1 3 4 2 2
2 5 2 5 2
3 6 6 7 6
4 1 7 3 1
5 9 4 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer but using `data.table` and `pmin`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(3,5,6,1,9), 
                 y = c(4,2,6,7,4))

dt[, z:= pmin(x,y)]
dt

# x y z
# 1: 3 4 3
# 2: 5 2 2
# 3: 6 6 6
# 4: 1 7 1
# 5: 9 4 4
```

Function `pmin` returns the parallel minima (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mc2d/versions/0.1-17/topics/pmin)

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `fifelse` in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, z := fifelse(x > y, y, x)]
```